# How to Average column on bottom of query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Ignore `'?DATE1::?'` it is just a prefix for users to input date range.

```
Select
       STARTDATEKEY 
       round(avg(Minutes),2) as Time  /*average for 1 day */
from   Table
where To_Date(to_char(StartDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
and To_Date(to_char(RESTOREDDATETIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
and FLAG = 0
group by STARTDATEKEY
```

Out will be 
 [image]

I need help showing average for column Time on bottom of **20130110 52.67**

note to editor/reviewer : I don't know if I should tag Oracle or SQL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ROLLUP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007413) grouping function.
Should be something like this:

```
Select
       STARTDATEKEY 
       round(avg(Minutes),2) as Time  /*average for 1 day */
from   Table
where To_Date(to_char(StartDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) >= To_Date('?DATE1::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
and To_Date(to_char(RESTOREDDATETIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')) <= To_Date('?DATE2::?','MM/DD/YYYY')
and FLAG = 0
group by ROLLUP(STARTDATEKEY)
```

[Here is a simplified sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b0db/2)

Comment: Consider this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks @gustavodidomenico, but since OP is using `oracle`, it's better to refer to the oracle docs...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for great function, and link, but I get error If I use that  `System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints. at System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints() at System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value) at `

Comment: @Mowgli: How are you using the results? Are you trying to insert them into a table with some or all of the mentioned constraints enforced? As you can see from the demo, the rollup row will have NULL in the STARTDATEKEY column. Or is the error really relevant to the query you are asking about?

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for that question, I found the problem but not the solution. I ran and tested `ROLLUP` directly to Oracle via SQLPLUS  it worked there(ran query), but it didn't work with the software I write query in, it is special software I write query in there(it would throw me error I paste above, if it has rollup in it) and it will published on a html/aspx webpage. Is there any other option I have to average Time column? thanks

Comment: @Mowgli, what is this software you're using ? maybe there is a solution, maybe you can post another question regarding this software... ROLLUP is a good and fast feature of the DB, pity not to use it